# starting Java 3D

Tags: java, 3d

i wanna know what is the best way to start coding a simple 3D ... (with java)
like a man walking around ... i know it's not so easy , but i believe it's not impossible :D
so .. is there a recommended tutorial or something???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Start with something like [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/).  Lots of great tutorials on their site using their scenegraph API.  It's where you want to end up eventually anyway, IMHO.
2. [NeHe Productions: OpenGL Tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=01).  These are great because they give you a lot of OpenGL info and instructions.  Note that all the code in the tutorial is C however, at the bottom of the tutorials are links to ports of the code to various platforms and languages, including Java.

Comment: Note that NeHe is quite outdated and generally not a recommended resource anymore. jMonkeyEngine on the other hand is an engine that I'd recommend, too.

Comment: jMonkeyEngine is widely used??

Answer (score 2):

You could start with [Java 3D API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html)   or [Java OpenGL (JOGL)](http://java.net/projects/jogl/).
I think, if you want something like OpenGL then you should consider about JOGL

Answer (score 2):

The best way to start is to find out a good and free 3d game engine. You should know something about 3d graphics: basic transformation, how to work with matrices (specially multiply order), etc.

I can recommend you [Lightweight Java Game Library](http://lwjgl.org/), [Ogre3D for Java](http://ogre4j.sourceforge.net/) or even jMonkeyEngine. Later you can try to use  OpenGL directly - its easy to learn, multiplatform 3D graphics library.

Comment: what's the best for making something looks good ,,, but i don't wanna waste too much time ... ??
i mean .. i wanna have a look about that before getting innn :D

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding of the scene graph-based and Java3D programming I recommend you to read [this](http://www.sdsc.edu/~nadeau/Courses/Siggraph99/) tutorial. It helps me very much